# Xcode: How can I rename all file extensions easily without doing it one by one, without loosing all the references to the targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, rename, target

In Xcode, I would like to rename all the files extensions from PNG to JPG easily.
I tried find and replace, but it only changes the names in storyboards, classes etc... not the file names.

**Find & Replace:**
[image]

**Files:**
[image: files to rename]

**References to targets:**
[image]

If I change the name only physically, it lots the file :

[image]
Is there a way to do it easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need multiple steps to achieve this.

1. Do your find & replace approach like you described
2. For renaming the files you do the following in the terminal.

   - `brew install rename`
   - `cd <path to your folder>` This is important. Make sure you are in the right folder, otherwise you rename more files than you want ;-).
   - `find . -exec rename -S '.png' '.jpg' {} +` This replaces every occurance of png to jpg recursively (this means including subfolders)
3. You have to rename the file references inside your Xcode-Project and all occurences in your the Assets.xcassets file

   - Close Xcode.
   - `cd <path to your folder>`
   - `find . -type f -name 'project.pbxproj' -exec sed -i '' s/.png/.jpg/ {} +`
   - `find . -type f -name 'Contents.json' -exec sed -i '' s/.png/.jpg/ {} +`
   - Open Xcode again

**Please make a commit or a backup before such operations.**

Comment: Hello @fl034 I tried it, but it doesn't change the name in XCode. I updated my ticket.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time @fl034. It works perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: Glad i could help!